# Is this subjunctive an adjunct?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> I remembered crying when I first lost a patient due to an infection
>   easily treatable, **had we had the antibiotics and the money to buy
>   them**. ([source](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?qid=5AWqw&l_cid=QNE001&l_st=1&returl=/qna/question/list.html?category_id=QNE001&))

There’s a subjunctive after adjective phrase and the former seems to be a condition for the latter. In this case, is the highlighted part an [adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_%28grammar%29) for adding the condition or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. *Had we had...* is in effect the condition (*IF*) clause of an implicit conditional (*IF...THEN*) construction. Verb forms with the *-able* suffix may be understood as **modal participles**:

- They express passive **voice**(=*BE VERBen*) and dynamic **modality** (=*CAN*).
- They  are unspecified with respect to **tense** (past/non-past), **aspect** (simple/perfect/progressive), and **epistemic modality** (factual/hypothetical/irrealis), all of which they take from their context.

*Treatable* is thus the verb of the consequence (*THEN*) clause and may be paraphrased

> infections *could have been treated* had we had the antibiotics ...